# Laravel blade returning just a part of slug

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

There is some mystic here.
I have a list of locations in database, each of them have their own slug, as : 
`cahul-163` , `anenii-noi-164` , `mascauti-167`

When I display in foreach that object, and echo the slug, it returns me only
`cahul`, `anenii-noi`, `mascauti`.

Where this mystic can live? :)

```
`@foreach($locations as $location)
   {{$location->name}}
   {{$location->slug}}
@endforeach
`
```

**EDIT:**
Problem is on the DB level probably. I just make a return of any location from controller, and the location object slug is `anenii-noi` instead of `anenii-noi-164`.  I double-checked my DB.  The slug for this table is `anenii-noi-164`!  What the hell ? :)

Comment: try putting cast in your Location model,
 protected $casts = [
        'slug' => 'string'
]; to see if it fixes the issue. to me it looks like the type of slug is not stringified before echoing

Comment: @DimitrisKontoulis tried. Doesn't work. What kind of type can that field have if it looks like `anenii-noi-164` and it's not a string ? :)
The thing is that I use that slug in some routes for `show` method. And in routes it works fine. Like going to route : `/locations/anenii-noi-164` takes me right page.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue , i have  tried in own project with slug and same strings as yours and they are displayed. If I were you , I would also try {{ (string) $location->slug }} to see if it makes any difference

Comment: As of your last edit, the issue points mostly in the Location model. Do you have any mutator/accessor associated with the slug attribute?

Comment: I changed from DB slug to any word, and anyway it returns me the same `anenii-noi` slug. May be it's a problem of caching ? I tried to delete, clear cache and everything but it doesn't work. What the.. ?:)